# How to count number of pages in SharePoint Site using powershell

Tags: 2010

How to count number of pages in Site and Sub Sites using powershell ??

Thanks

Comment: What kind of pages? Site page or other page?

Comment: pages in pages library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the script below :

```
 $URL="http://site.Site.com"
 $BASETEMPLATE="Pages"


    $site = Get-SPSite $URL     
    $totalItems = 0     
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)     
    {         
        $lists = $web.Lists         
        for ($i=0; $i -le $lists.Count – 1; $i++)          
        {             
            $list = $lists[$i]             
            if ($list.Title -eq "Pages")             
            {                 
                $totalItems = $totalItems + $list.Items.Count             
            }         
        }             
    }     
    $site.Dispose()     
    write-host $totalItems
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sitecollURL = " "
$totalsubsites = 0

$site = Get-SPSite $sitecollURL

foreach($subsites in $site.AllWebs)
{
  $totalsubsites++;
}
write-host $totalsubsites
```